# ClassCastException starting the ReportEngine with Birt

Tags: java, report, birt, business-intelligence, classcastexception

I am trying to generate some pdfReports using BIRT (not my technological choice, I would have used JasperReports). Here is my code:

```
protected IReportEngine getEngine() {
    if (engine == null) {
        try {

            config = new EngineConfig();
            config.setEngineHome(getReportEngineHome());

            Platform.startup(config);
            IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform.createFactoryObject(IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);
            engine = factory.createReportEngine(config);


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("Can't create report engine " + ex); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
    }

    return engine;
}
```

I took this code from the BIRT book, so I am expecting it to be working, but when the casting to the (IReportEngineFactory) occurs, I get a classCastException :

```
Can't create report engine java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.ReportEngineFactory cannot be cast to org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.IReportEngineFactory ERROR [[FrontController]] Servlet.service() for servlet FrontController threw exception
```

I don't even understand why the ReportEngineFactory.java class is not even in the BIRT distribution nor in any other distribution I was able to find lurking on the web!

Comment: Can you expand on what version of BIRT you are using? Are you reporting from the application or through Tomcat?

Comment: This code should work, however i don't understand why you don't find the ReportEngineFactory.class? This class is located in the birt runtime, which is the main jar of the distribution. With birt 4.3.1 it is named like this: org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.3.1.<build-version>.jar

Comment: I resolved the issue moving the libs under /ReportEngine/lib to the folder /Web-INF/lib directly... I am facing another problem though, but the previous one should be solved this way! Also adding the jars to the classpath of JBOSS in the Ecliplse IDE configuration was not enough... I manually copied the jars in the structure of the webapp once it was deployed under JBOSS, in the folder /server/default/deploy/nameofmywebapp/lib